# Size of Android UI mockups?

Tags: android

I want to design some mockup interfaces for some Android apps. I would like them to be able to nicely scale up and down depending on the resolution of the mobile device being used.

What would be the best image size to design these mockup interface in?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No resolution is optimal as there are many Android devices with many different resolutions; if you want to create a flexible layout without too much work, you should use Nine-Patch techniques, some info about nine-patch:

1. http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html
2. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html

Comment: I am just getting started and do not yet have the SDK and am just designing mockup interfaces in Photoshop and Illustrator. Can I take the artwork I am designing in Photoshop and Illustrator and use all of it in an interface?

Comment: @user484893: make sure to draw your UI elements into separate layers in Photoshop, so that you can later export them as separate images; especially for the scalable elements, as you want to process them for nine-patch. While designing the UI, take extra care to make them easily nine-patchable, or otherwise you'd have to redraw them for each different resolutions. Think really carefully on which part of the UI should stretch and which part should not.

Comment: How can I draw the images in Photoshop or Illustrator and make them nine-patchable?

Comment: @user484893: have you read the referenced article? a nine-patch image is a regular image, except they have special markings in the border to describe to NinePatch class how the image should be scaled. You can draw the borders in any image editor, but there is also a program in Android SDK that makes it easy to draw nine-patch image.

Answer (score 0):

I would say 320x480, which are nice numbers to work with, the grid is easily settable (grid of 16 or 32 px) and this is a pretty average display-size for touch screens.

Answer (score 0):

I would use 480x800 and scale up/down based on the resolution/density of the device.